# Update documents in array via Mongo's $addToSet in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to upsert documents within an array of documents via the C# Driver for MongoDB. I manage to modify existing array elements via $set & arrayFilters, but struggle to add non-existing elements via $addToSet. 
I would be glad about any suggestion, even if there is a completely different way.

My simplified class in C#

```
internal class TimeSeries
{
    [BsonId]
    internal Name;

    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
    internal Dictionary<DateTime, double> Container;
}

// add a test document
void foo()
{
    var coll = _myDatabase.GetCollection<TimeSeries>("myColl"); 
    var res = coll.InsertOne(new TimeSeries() 
        { Name = "abc", Container = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>() 
            {{new DateTime(2000,1,1),20}}
        });
}
```

$set and $addToSet in the Mongo Shell work fine:

```
// modify the existing value to 30
db.myColl.update( {"_id":"abc"}, {$set: {"Container.$[loc].v":30}}, {arrayFilters:[{"loc.k":new Date("2000-01-01")}]})

// add if no existent
db.myColl.update( {"_id":"abc"}, {$addToSet: {"Container": {"k":new Date("2000-02-01"),"v":200}}})
```

In C# I can reproduce $set, but get a "Specific Cast is not valid" error for $addToSet.

```
var filter = Builders<TimeSeries>.Filter.Eq("_id", "abc");

var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>>()
                    {new BsonDocument("loc.k", new DateTime(2000,1,1))}; 

// $set
var upsert = Builders<TimeSeries>.Update.Set("Container.$[loc].v", 30);
var resUpt = coll.UpdateOne(filter, upsert, new UpdateOptions { ArrayFilters = arrayFilters })

// $addToSet
var upsert_add = Builders<TimeSeries>.Update.AddToSet("Container", new BsonDocument { { "k", new DateTime(2000, 2, 1) }, { "v", 50} });
var res_add = coll.UpdateOne(filter, upsert_add); // Specific Cast is not valid
```

Comment: `Builders<Curve>.Update` produces `UpdateDefinition<Curve>` objects, not `UpdateDefinition<TimeSeries>` objects.

Comment: @john Thanks, just a typo posting the question

Comment: @SockenLoch - please tell me you eventually figured this out...